# PHP Application Caching Questions (Aka what Caching Solution)

Tags: php, caching, doctrine

I just started a new Project with a Team.
We are planning to build something with php.

I just stumbled about an Issue that I currently don't know how to solve.

We have for caching two different approaches currently in discussion.

We can either decide to go for memcache or redis

Both have the kind of equal downsides with the clustering.
The app itself should reside on the following setup:

one major Web Server (nginx) fires requests two n app servers.
The App Servers get the source code within an nfs mount (web server to app server is handled on an seperated 10GB Network).

Each AppServer should have its own cache server (for performance).

We want to include in the cache the following data:

1. session storage
2. doctrine cache stuff (metadata, query, result)
3. email queue
4. application cache (like the Acl Data etc.)

Both solutions don't offer a real master master replication which should be done as you can't tell to 100% on which server the user remains on.

Redis offers an Clustered solution, but it does not support more then One Database. And this is the problem. Each Sandbox needs its own cache to prevent interference with other sandbox sets or even the productive system.

So what solution should we go for?
We take everything into consideration that you could give us as hint.

:)
Chris

Comment: `Each AppServer should have its own cache server (for performance)`, if your doing full text searches I would suggest using sphinx instead of caching, Sphinx is about / at least 20x faster the a database, in my testing...  We use this in production for a few things.  55k queries per minute is pretty good.  You can also distribute the index across multiple servers etc..

Comment: Ok, forgot to mention. 
Searching is done using elastic search which is clustered over our database servers (1 master server, 2 read only slaves)